# How to assert that a dependency was called using `async` in a Jest test?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, jestjs, assertions

I have a service that can decorate an async function with a configuration-toggled alternate behavior:

```
// decorator.js
const config = require('./config');
const logger = require('./logger');

function addAlternateBehavior(originalAsyncFunction, alternateAsyncFunction) {
    return async () => {
        if (config.useAlternateBehavior) {
            await alternateAsyncFunction();
        } else {
            await originalAsyncFunction();
        }
        logger.info('Behavior finished executing');
    };
}

exports.addAlternateBehavior = addAlternateBehavior;
```

I have a Jest unit test that verifies that the alternate behavior gets called when configured accordingly:

```
// decorator.test.js
const decorator = require('./decorator');
const config = require('./config');

it('returned function should use alternate behavior when configured to do so', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const originalAsyncFunction = jest.fn();
    const alternateAsyncFunction = jest.fn();
    config.useAlternateBehavior = true;

    // Act
    const decoratedFunction = decorator
        .addAlternateBehavior(originalAsyncFunction, alternateAsyncFunction);
    await decoratedFunction();

    // Assert
    expect(originalAsyncFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
    expect(alternateAsyncFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

I want to assert that when you call the decorated function with `await`, it also awaits the expected behavior.  However, in the decorator, if I change `await alternateAsyncFunction();` to just `alternateAsyncFunction()`, my unit test still passes.

How can I assert, in a unit test, that the function decorated by `addAlternateBehavior()` awaits the `alternateAsyncFunction` or `originalAsyncFunction`?

Comment: At the risk of telling you what you already know, including/omitting `await` from `await foo();` will make no difference to `foo.mock.calls.length`. `foo()` will be called regardless of `await`. Consequently, your two `expect` expressions, as currently written, will correctly reflect whether `alternateAsyncFunction()` or `originalAsyncFunction()` was called. Of course, the downstream behaviour will differ with/without `await`, but that's not a concern because you are not about to permanently delete `await` .... are you?

Comment: In fact, since awaiting is immaterial, `await` can be omitted from `await decoratedFunction();`. 
You can write `decorator.addAlternateBehavior(originalAsyncFunction, alternateAsyncFunction)();`. 
And since the `it()` callback is now await-free, `async` can also be omitted and your test will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `async` functions an implementation that waits at least two event loop cycles before calling an inner `mock`.  Then test if that inner `mock` was called:

```
const decorator = require('./decorator');
const config = require('./config');

it('returned function should use alternate behavior when configured to do so', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const originalInner = jest.fn();
    const originalAsyncFunction = jest.fn(async () => {
      await Promise.resolve();
      await Promise.resolve();
      originalInner();
    });
    const alternateInner = jest.fn();
    const alternateAsyncFunction = jest.fn(async () => {
      await Promise.resolve();
      await Promise.resolve();
      alternateInner();
    });
    config.useAlternateBehavior = true;

    // Act
    const decoratedFunction = decorator
        .addAlternateBehavior(originalAsyncFunction, alternateAsyncFunction);
    await decoratedFunction();

    // Assert
    expect(originalAsyncFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
    expect(originalInner.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
    expect(alternateAsyncFunction.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(alternateInner.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

If the function created by `addAlternateBehavior()` doesn't `await` then the inner `mock` won't get called.

Note that two `await Promise.resolve();` statements are necessary since the first one resolves during the event loop cycle that runs during `await decoratedFunction();`